# How can I organize my code so that repeating try except clauses only exist once?

Tags: python, try-catch, except

The code in the try statement is going to be different, but the try except statement itself is always the same. How can I make this less redundant?

```
def cloudflare_add_zone(ctx, url, jumpstart, organization):
    try:

        if organization:
            ctx.create_zone(url, jumpstart, organization)
        else:
            ctx.create_zone(url, jumpstart)
        click.echo('Zone successfully created: %s' % url)

    except HTTPServiceError, e:
        code = str(e.details['errors'][0]['code'])
        message = e.details['errors'][0]['message']
        click.echo(code + ":" + message)

def cloudflare_add_record(ctx, domain, name, type, content, ttl):
    try:

        payload = {
            'type': type,
            'name': name,
            'content': content
        }
        if ttl:
            payload['ttl'] = ttl
        zone_id = ctx.get_zone_by_name(domain).get('id')
        ctx.create_dns_record(zone_id, payload)

    except HTTPServiceError, e:
        code = str(e.details['errors'][0]['code'])
        message = e.details['errors'][0]['message']
        click.echo(code + ":" + message)
```

Comment: Really bad way. Put the try except where you call the func

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write a decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def http_safe(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except HTTPServiceError, e:
            click.echo('{[code]}: {[message]}'.format(e.details['errors'][0]))
   return wrapper
```

And then use it:

```
@http_safe
def cloudflare_add_zone(ctx, url, jumpstart, organization):
    if organization:
        ctx.create_zone(url, jumpstart, organization)
    else:
        ctx.create_zone(url, jumpstart)
    click.echo('Zone successfully created: %s' % url)
```

Comment: For the echo use format: `click.echo("{[code]}: {[message]}".format(e.details['errors'][0])`.

Comment: Very nice, looks much cleaner now. I don't understand decorator's completely yet, so I'm definitely going to try and grasp the concept of them better now.

Comment: @Daniel That code is giving me an error and I can't figure it out, so I had to stick with the regular echo. How does this line work exactly? (I fixed the ending parenthesis before trying it)